# php optimize rendering upon webpage load

Tags: php, html, optimization, rendering

My php webpage contains hundreds if not thousands of buttons that can belong to up to 4-5 classes.

I am generating all the buttons upon loading the page and then display them according to user interactions using simple js getElementsByClassName.

The initial loading of the page is very fast (<1s) on my computer's local server but very slow (~30s) on the production website. Once the page is loaded all the interactions (hide/show) are very fast.

The google performance tool shows that 80% of the loading time is spent on rendering.

What would be the best method to shorten the loading page?

I tried using php classes for the buttons but wasn't then able to change their display properties.

I'm leaning towards trying DOMDocument class, but I'm not sure if it would work with the method of "include $page.php" (among others) that I'm using.

Any helpful advice would be great :)

Cheers

Comment: You should think about restructuring your markup. Why do you need hundreds of buttons in your markup?